# Материалы по Clean Architecture в Android

Tags: android, архитектура, mvp, dagger, moxy

Имею 3 года практики в Android разработке и недавно начал интересоваться такими вещами, как DI, Moxy, Cicerone и Clean Architecture. Здесь, на SO, я почти не вижу вопросов, относящихся к этой теме. В телеграмме очень мало людей состоят в чатах по ним. Как я понял, эти вещи изучаются в самом конце, на пути к "званию" *Senior Developer*'а и сложнее них нет ничего. Год назад я не понимал суть Dagger'а и MVP. Сейчас я, кажется, понимаю зачем это все нужно: так как разработка почти всегда командная, у всех участников проекта должны быть определенные стандарты проектирования. Разработчики будут лучше понимать друг друга.

Все же полностью понять эти вещи я не могу, я думаю здесь есть те, кто тоже их не понимал, но сейчас вполне их использует и счастлив. Хочу у них спросить какие книги они читали и как трудно там, в клине? Из мной прочитанных и полностью изученных, являются *"Философия Java"* и *"Java 8 Полное руководство"*. Если Clean Architecture относится к архитектуре кода, то мне нужно сначала прочитать, например, *"Паттерны проектирования"* и *"Эффективное программирование"*? Какие книги я должен для начала прочитать?

Также хотел бы узнать какая сейчас средне ситуация с ними на рынке, они уже *must have* или пока еще в *будет плюсом*?

Пожалуйста, не пишите "Не понимаешь - не используй", я действительно хочу понять это. **Давайте те, кто в этом уже разбирается, оставит тут информацию о книгах и свои советы.**

Спасибо. Думаю, что книги, которые вы посоветуете (и Clean Architecture в общем) будут интересны многим.

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что DI, Moxy и и др. изучаются на пути к сеньору. Я когда ходил по собеседованиям на Android Junior'а у меня активно спрашивали имею ли я опыт использования этих библиотек и паттернов.
Это и заставило меня их изучать.
На тестовых заданиях мне ставили в минус то, что не использован паттерн MVP или DI.
И только на последнем собеседовании, когда я сказал что изучаю эти технологии и описал их суть, меня и приняли на работу.

Comment: @YungBlade, ого, поторопился я с выводами

Comment: Flippy, говорите 3 года практики и сейчас только про DI спрашиваете?) Я еще учусь и на собеседования ходить не пробовал, но вижу на рынке, описанных вами знаний требуют от junior, хотя бы понимая. Где то сами готовы помочь, лишь бы вы были хорошо знакомы со структурами данных, ооп , Java и Android SDK. Но даже в таких вакансиях пишут Будет плюсом знание всего чего вы описали. Так что это всё junior и без этих знаний ваше место займет кто-нибудь другой.  На самом деле всё не так сложно как вы описываете. Это просто страх перед неизведанным, но и не так быстро. На DI я потратил неделю

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture  вот тут есть проекты, которые в гугле писали , сперва там mvp реализуют, а потом в этот же проект вводят чистую архитектуру.  В общем лучший способ понять всё это - читать хороший код и разбирать его целыми днями. ЧИтать статьи нужно, но это только начало и зацикливаться на них не нужно.   https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=@Android_Architecture       Зря говорите что людей мало в телеграмме,  в этой группе вы можете дублировать вопросы связанные с архитектурой и кто знает , ответит  на stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Роберт Мартин, человек описавший чистую архитектуру, написал книгу с соответствующим названием - ["Чистая архитектура"](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%98%D1%81.html?id=d6JSDwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y). Его фундаментальный труд в виде статьи лежит [здесь](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html). Разъяснения касательно разработки под android, и clean architecture в целом, расписаны в [этом](https://habr.com/company/mobileup/blog/335382/) труде. Материалы по второй и третьей ссылке дадут вам надежную почву для старта.

Comment: Пожалуй, самая лучшая книга для осмысления заданного вопроса. Ещё можно вдогонку Эванса порекомендовать, но строго после чистой архитектуры.

Comment: Прочитал статью на хабре, сейчас на нем же читаю статьи про конкретный андроид, код ищу

Comment: @Flippy, https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture. Образец от разработчика, который предложил использовать clean architecture в android. Ссылка на его статью есть в статье на хабре